# load xml data from external site the pasre data and then send response back in xml to browser

Tags: xml, parsing, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to request data from an API parse specific data from it and return the response in xml.

What I have so far is this which works fine but only returns text rather than xml

```
<%
dim objXMLL
Dim objXML, objXSL, x

Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
objXML.async = False
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.Load "http://www.theapisite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=name@thesite.com&EncryptedPassword=2873287372372326372638374837473473674634763784637843648736&EDI_Name=Generic\Products&SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,pe.Availability&WHERE_Column=p.ProductCode&WHERE_Value=1430-09"
objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

For Each x In objXML.documentElement.selectNodes(".//Products")
Response.write x.nodename & " = " & x.Text 
Next
%>
```

Here is the XML returned from the API.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xmldata>
         <Products>
              <ProductCode>1430-09</ProductCode>
              <ProductID>37717</ProductID>
              <Availability>Out of Stock</Availability>
         </Products>
    </xmldata>
```

This is what I want to send back to the browser as the response instead of the text. How do I only send the XML I need and return it in the response with the names as shown.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>
         <Products>
              <Product>1430-09</Product>
              <ID>37717</ID>
         </Products>
    </data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want transform your http request response XML to another schema and write that to the browser? If this the case, you can use an [XSL Transform](http://www.perfectxml.com/msxmlXSLT.asp). Or you can programmatically create a new xml document in your ASP and copy the data over as appropriate

```vb
Dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc.async = false
' add the xml processing instruction
Dim instruction
Set instruction = xmldoc.createProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""")
xmldoc.appendChild instruction 
' create the root nodes
Dim data: set data = xmldoc.createElement("data")
xmldoc.appendChild data
Dim products: set products = xmldoc.createElement("Products")
data.appendChild products

Dim x
For Each x In objXML.documentElement.selectNodes(".//Products")
     ' get each child node
     Dim productcode: Set productcode = x.selectSingleNode("ProductCode")
     Dim productid: Set productid = x.selectSingleNode("ProductID")
     ' pass over the data from old node to new
     Dim product: Set product = xmldoc.createElement("Product")
     product.text = productcode.text
     products.appendChild product
     Dim id: set id = xmldoc.createElement("ID")
     id.text = productid.text
     products.appendChild id
Next
' write the final xml to the response stream
Response.Write xmldoc.xml
```

Depending on the size of the input XML, you may want to compare the performance between this and using an XSL transform

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to write that. It works great. (had to remove your Dim x though) I think I may need to look into the XSL Transform method cause I will potentially have hundreds if not thousands of entries. If your don't mind, how can I get it to send the result as a XML file instead of as a response to the browser? THX again!!!

Comment: the DomDocument (ie both `objXML` and `xmldoc`) have a `save([destination])` method which allows you to write to disk

Comment: btw, +1 for the use of a `DomDocument` to run a http request. I didn't know you could do that, I've always created a `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` object explicitly.

Comment: thx, I used xmldoc.save "/sample.xml" but got "access is denied". I really don't want to save it per se to the server but send the result automatically to the user. Anyway to do this?

Comment: not sure what you mean - isn't sending it to the browser (ie `Response.Write xmldoc.xml`) the same as sending the result automatically to the user?

Comment: when saving, you will need a writeable directory on the server, and you probably want to use `Server.MapPath()` to work out the right path.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean is there a way to have it download to the user as a file, for instance a "save as" dialog box opens up asking the user where they want to save the file on there machine.

Comment: yeah, you can do that. You need to set the headers, something like `Response.addHeader "Content-type", "text/xml": Response.addHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=download.xml"`. Do this before sending content to the client

Comment: That worked fantastic!!! Exactly what I also wanted to do besides the original question.